# Launch any browser with Notepad++ RUN

Tags: notepad++

The shortcuts.xml file looks correct. Could it be the file location? I copied and pasted a project into the program. Should I have imported it?

The file location is file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project. Firefox, IE, and Chrome can’t find the file at /C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project

```
<UserDefinedCommands>
<Command name="Launch in Firefox" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="88">firefox &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
<Command name="Launch in IE" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="73">iexplore &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
<Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">chrome &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
<Command name="Launch in Safari" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="70">safari &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
<Command name="Get php help" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="112">http://www.php.net/%20$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
<Command name="Google Search" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="113">http://www.google.com/search?q=$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
<Command name="Wikipedia Search" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="114">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
<Command name="Open file" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="116">$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe $(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
<Command name="Open in another instance" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="117">$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe $(CURRENT_WORD) -nosession -multiInst</Command>
<Command name="Send via Outlook" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="79">outlook /a &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
</UserDefinedCommands>
```

This is the name of the file that I want to preview.

file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project

This is the message that I am getting:

Firefox can’t find the file at /C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project

Comment: Is your file named `Project`? Can you run in Firefox any other file (from different location)? Also remember that you can't run newly created file without saving it first.

Comment: Hello! I was able to open a saved web page in another location, but I was not able to open a file in another location with code in it. This was a helpful way of thinking that I could not have come up with on my own. Thank you.